# jQuery mousemove animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I'm using the mousemove event handler with jQuery:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) { updateDownloadPosition(e); } );
```

It works perfectly in Chrome but every other browser I've tried the mousemove event isn't fired until the mouse stops moving, instead of constantly every time it moves.

**--EDIT--**

Ok so as Tim Down rightly pointed out, its not the mousemove event, its my function, so now my focus is on my animation function:

```
paralaxArray[i].object.animate(
            {marginLeft: newX},
            {duration: 3000,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo'});
```

In order to get this to reset properly on mousemove I was using the stop() function:

```
paralaxArray[i].object.stop().animate(
```

...but this produces choppy animation in chrome so now I'm using clearQueue:

```
paralaxArray[i].object.clearQueue();
paralaxArray[i].object.animate(
            {marginLeft: newX},
            {duration: 3000,
            easing: 'easeOutExpo'});
```

But doing it this way (and with stop() ) causes all browsers other than chrome to only animate once the mouse has stopped moving. What could be causing this?? Am I going to have to write my own animation update function?

Thanks again :)

Thanks

Comment: You're absolutely sure that the `updateDownloadPosition()` function isn't to blame?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to finish off this question, I did end up writing my own animation function in the end which then worked perfectly.